# Is there a special game over in System Shock 1 final boss fight?

Tags: system-shock

I have a vague recollection that if you failed in the SHODAN boss fight at the end of System Shock 1, you didn't get the standard Cortex Reaver game over video but something else instead.

> Yeah, her face fills up the screen completely but wasn't there something after that? Kicked back to DOS instead of main menu?

Is this correct or am I imagining things?